# PySpark to_json loses column name of struct inside array

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate a json string from a nested pyspark DataFrame, but am losing key values.
My initial Dataset is similar to the following:

```
data = [
    {"foo": [1, 2], "bar": [4, 5], "buzz": [7, 8]},
    {"foo": [1], "bar": [4], "buzz": [7]},
    {"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6], "buzz": [7, 8, 9]},
]
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(data))
df.show()
## +---------+---------+---------+
## |      bar|     buzz|      foo|
## +---------+---------+---------+
## |   [4, 5]|   [7, 8]|   [1, 2]|
## |      [4]|      [7]|      [1]|
## |[4, 5, 6]|[7, 8, 9]|[1, 2, 3]|
## +---------+---------+---------+
```

I then zip each of the columns together using arrays_zip:

```
df_zipped = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        "zipped",
        F.arrays_zip(
            F.col("foo"),
            F.col("bar"),
            F.col("buzz"),
        )
    )
)
df_zipped.printSchema()
root
 |-- bar: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- buzz: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- foo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- zipped: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- bar: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- buzz: long (nullable = true)
```

The problem is using to_json on the zipped array. It loses the foo, bar, and buzz key values, and instead saves the keys as the element index

```
(
    df_zipped
    .withColumn("zipped", F.to_json("zipped"))
    .select("zipped")
    .show(truncate=False)
)
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|zipped                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"0":1,"1":4,"2":7},{"0":2,"1":5,"2":8}]                    |
|[{"0":1,"1":4,"2":7}]                                        |
|[{"0":1,"1":4,"2":7},{"0":2,"1":5,"2":8},{"0":3,"1":6,"2":9}]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I keep "bar", "buzz", and "foo" instead of the 0, 1, 2?

Comment: Not pretty but you can manually build a string using `transform`: something like `F.expr("""transform(zipped, x -> concat('{"foo":', x['foo'], '"bar":', x['bar'], '"buzz":', x['buzz'], '}'))""")`

Answer (score 2):

Manually specifying the schema works too:
For the foo, bar, and buzz fields, the array on top of the elements must have been named, not at the actual datafields themselves

```
data = [
    {"foo": [1, 2], "bar": [4, 5], "buzz": [7, 8]},
    {"foo": [1], "bar": [4], "buzz": [7]},
    {"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6], "buzz": [7, 8, 9]},
]
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(data))
df.show()
+---------+---------+---------+
|      bar|     buzz|      foo|
+---------+---------+---------+
|   [4, 5]|   [7, 8]|   [1, 2]|
|      [4]|      [7]|      [1]|
|[4, 5, 6]|[7, 8, 9]|[1, 2, 3]|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Then defining and casting to the schema manually:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("foo", IntegerType()),
    StructField("bar", IntegerType()),
    StructField("buzz", IntegerType()),
])

df_zipped = (
    df_test
    .select(
        F.arrays_zip(
            F.col("foo"), 
            F.col("bar"), 
            F.col("buzz"),
                )
        .alias("zipped")
            )
    .filter(F.col("zipped").isNotNull())
    .select(F.col("zipped").cast(ArrayType(schema)))
)
```

This results in the desired solution:

```
(
    df_zipped
    .withColumn("zipped", F.to_json("zipped"))
    .select("zipped")
    .show(truncate=False)
)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|zipped                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"foo":1,"bar":4,"buzz":7},{"foo":2,"bar":5,"buzz":8}]                           |
|[{"foo":1,"bar":4,"buzz":7}]                                                      |
|[{"foo":1,"bar":4,"buzz":7},{"foo":2,"bar":5,"buzz":8},{"foo":3,"bar":6,"buzz":9}]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

note: Casting as LongType in the schema does not work

Answer (score 1):

This is not a super pretty answer (because you have to specify the keys explicitly), but better than [what I put in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816830/pyspark-to-json-loses-column-name-of-struct-inside-array/63818878#comment112851754_63816830).

Use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) with [`map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map):

```
df_zipped.withColumn(
    "zipped", 
    F.to_json(
        F.expr(
            """transform(zipped, x -> map('foo', x['foo'], 'bar', x['bar'], 'buzz', x['buzz']))"""
        )
    )
).select('zipped').show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|zipped                                                                            |
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[{"foo":1,"bar":4,"buzz":7},{"foo":2,"bar":5,"buzz":8}]                           |
#|[{"foo":1,"bar":4,"buzz":7}]                                                      |
#|[{"foo":1,"bar":4,"buzz":7},{"foo":2,"bar":5,"buzz":8},{"foo":3,"bar":6,"buzz":9}]|
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yeah thank you for the answer. It works which is great. I was hoping for a way that you do not have to manually define the keys/schema but that may not be possible

Comment: you could build the expression dynamically by querying the schema to get the names of the keys..it's complicated and not sure if it's worth the effort. In any case, you specify the keys in the `arrays_zip`

Comment: I am having this same problem but I can't do create_map as my columns aren't all the same type. Any ideas?